# Can I use camel-spring version 2.25.x with camel-core version 2.23.x

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, fuse

I am using below Red Hat Fuse BOM for my camel application to get the camel dependencies for my project. It returns camel dependencies version 2.23.x

```
<dependencyManagement> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.redhat-fuse</groupId>
        <artifactId>fuse-springboot-bom</artifactId>
        <version>7.7.0.fuse-sb2-770010-redhat-00001</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
<dependencyManagement>
```

My Maven is set to get the dependency through JFrog, which blocks **camel-spring-2.23.x** version due to some vulnerability found in this version of jar as per our client security policy. My question is, Will it be correct to specify the **camel-spring** dependency in pom.xml as below to download  **2.25.x** version and let the other camel lib dependencies as **2.23.x** ? Is it going to cause any issue in amy camel application due to different camel library versions?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
    <version>2.25.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: It might work but will eventually lead to issues. Never mix jars from different versions of a framework, that will only lead to weird to debug issues with version conflicts etc.

Comment: Red Hat Fuse has all its released JARs in their maven repository, so you should download it from there